# Scroll div until top of footer

Tags: javascript

i've been looking for this for a couple of days but still no joy!

I would like to have a div scroll in a fixed position until it gets to the top of the footer.

Here is a fiddle of what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/uk4mC/

I'm using this JQuery code but this uses pixels to determine when the div stops. I would like to use the top of the footer as the stop point:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
var scrollVal = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#floating-container').css('top',scrollVal+'px');
if (scrollVal < 50) { 
    $('#floating-container').css('top','50px');
}
if (scrollVal > 2347) {
    $('#floating-container').css('top','2347px');    
}
});
```

The issue is that i am using a CMS and the client will be adding text to the page so the second value will change depending on what they add.

I hope i've been clear enough! please let me know if you require more details.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check in the scroll event if the bottom edge of your `div` is lower than the footer. If it is, place the div at the position of the `footer` minus the height of the `div`.

```
$(function(){
    var container = $('#floating-container');
    var minTop = $('header').outerHeight();
    var maxTop = $('footer').offset().top - container.outerHeight(); 

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var scrollVal = $(document).scrollTop();

        container.css('top', scrollVal);

        if (scrollVal < minTop) { 
            container.css('top', minTop);
        }

        if (container.offset().top > maxTop ) {
            container.css('top', maxTop );    
        }
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk4mC/6/)**

And, a much shorter variant of the script above:

```
$(function(){
    var container = $('#floating-container');
    var minTop = $('header').outerHeight();
    var maxTop = $('footer').offset().top - container.outerHeight(); 

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        container.css('top', Math.min( Math.max(minTop, $(document).scrollTop()), maxTop ));
    });
});
```

[**Short version fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uk4mC/7/).

Comment: Fiddle looks good but I think you could cache the floating-container jquery object

Comment: Updated -> Added a much shorter implementation.

Comment: What if I want the floating-container always at the bottom of the screen instead of top? (but stopping at the footer)

Comment: Well, then instead of placing it at `scrollVal`, you have to place it at `scrollVal + window.innerHeight - divHeight` , or something like that.

Comment: Sorry, i am pretty new at this and I am still learning but do you mean something like this: `container.css('top', scrollVal + window.innerHeight - divHeight);`?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the position of the footers top when you load the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/uk4mC/1/

```
var footerTop = $('#text-block').position().top;
```

and then use that as a trigger:

```
if (scrollVal < footerTop) { }
```