# Adding/removing a class with jQuery when scrolling inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, sticky

I have a child `<div>` which has `position: fixed;` applied by adding a class of `is-active` when you scroll past the top of it's parent `<div>`.

Is it possible to fix the position of the child at the end of the parent as you scroll beyond the end of the parent? And then re-apply the class 'is-active' to the child when you scroll back up above the end of the parent?

Essentially I'd like the fixed position of the child to only be active within it's parent. I want to achieve what `position: sticky;` can do without the polyfill overhead and lack of browser support. Is this possible?

Here's what I have currently:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="nav">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="end">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200rem;
    margin: 10rem 0 0;
    background: red;
}

.end {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40rem;
    background: green;
}

.nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 30rem;
    background: blue;

    &.is-active {
        position: fixed;
        top: 2rem;
        left: 2rem;
    }

}
```

jQuery:

```
var $nav = $('.nav');
var $outer = $('.outer');

$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var $parentOffset = $outer.offset().top;
    var $parentHeight = $outer.height();
    var $navHeight = $nav.height();
    if($scroll > $parentOffset && $scroll < ($parentHeight - $navHeight)) {
      $nav.addClass('is-active');
    }
    else {
      $nav.removeClass('is-active');
    });
});
```

Here's Codepen with a working example also: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/BwXBLv

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: This might help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811702/scroll-div-until-top-of-footer

Answer (score -1):

i just changed it now sticky header is working
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxKPbj

```
if($scroll > $parentOffset && $scroll ) {
                    $nav.addClass('is-active');
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the child div keeps the class past the end of the parent div.

Comment: Please add more details/context of what you are trying to make.

Comment: @VarunJain I want a div to float inside the parameters of a parent div.